# Rails Routes and Static Pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xml

I'm working on a ruby-on-rails app that would write XML files for each section on a page. So instead of querying the database every time the user makes a request it would simply call the XML file that corresponds to that page and the javascript will parse the file. On the rails side there will be a content management system. When user is ready to commit all their content changes they will hit the publish file at which point the data which possibly was already saved in the database will now be written to an xml file.

The challenge is that I want all the xml files to live inside a folder in the main project directory called xml_display.

How do I configure the routes.rb to take a request like... myhost.com/display_xml/pagename.xml
and return the static page in rails_project_root/display_xml/pagename.xml

I've looked into High Voltage and it doesn't seem to be the solution I'm looking for.
I hope this sounds interesting to you.

Comment: Is it critical that the display_xml directory be a direct child of the project root?  You could make it public/display_xml and there'd be no routing issues at all.  Alternatively you could symlink public/display_xml to display_xml..

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a controller that redirects to your static files something like the following:

routes.rb

```
match '/display_xml/:id', :action => 'display'
```

display_xml_controller.rb

```
class DisplayXMLController
  def display
    redirect_to "http://#{host_domain}/static_xml_dir_in_public/#{params[:id]}.xml
  end
end
```

You need to set host_domain to wherever you are running from. Most set up in a config.yml